# syscall - How to use LPWSTR in Go?

Tags: windows, go, system-calls

I'm trying to create a thin wrapper of Windows MMDevice API for Go, and I faced the problem about Windows data types for strings.
According to the documentation of [IMMDevice::GetId method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371407(v=vs.85).aspx), it takes the parameter below:

```
HRESULT GetId(
    [out] LPWSTR *ppstrId
);
```

And here is my Go code that corresponds to the method above. ([github.com/moutend/ywca/immdevice_windows.go:13](https://github.com/moutend/ywca))

```
func getId(mmd *IMMDevice, strId *uint16) (err error) {
    hr, _, _ := syscall.Syscall(
        mmd.VTable().GetId,
        2,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(mmd)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(strId)),
        0)
    // ...
}
```

My understand is that the LPWSTR is the pointer to the array of uint16 values, but it causes invalid pointer error.
What type should I use in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a pointer to a pointer. The LPWSTR type is a `wchar_t*` and therefor the parameter in that method is a `wchar_t**`.

You are not passing in a string buffer for the method to fill. The method will allocate memory with `CoTaskMemAlloc` and return this memory address back to you after it has been filled. You are responsible for freeing this memory with `CoTaskMemAlloc`.

Comment: The cause of confusion was my misunderstanding about a pointer value. Thank you for helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is read the documentation for the Windows function.

> [IMMDevice::GetId
>   method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371407(v=vs.85).aspx),
>
> ```
> HRESULT GetId(
>     [out] LPWSTR *ppstrId
> );
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> `ppstrId` [out]
>
> Pointer to a pointer variable into which the method writes the address
>   of a null-terminated, wide-character string containing the endpoint
>   device ID. The method allocates the storage for the string. The caller
>   is responsible for freeing the storage, when it is no longer needed,
>   by calling the CoTaskMemFree function. If the GetId call fails,
>   *ppstrId is NULL. For information about CoTaskMemFree, see the Windows SDK documentation.
>
> Return value
>
> If the method succeeds, it returns S_OK. If it fails, possible return
>   codes include, but are not limited to, the values shown in the
>   following table.

In particular, "ppstrId [out] Pointer to a pointer variable ..." You have `strId *uint16` or `*pstrId` when I would expect you to have `strId **uint16` or `*ppstrId`.